# selctor:hover.class applied before hover

Tags: css, hover

I want to apply a  link selector hover effect which includes bottom border underline in an unordered list.  Really, I know I can do a simple underline using a border-bottom: #FFFFFF solid 2px;, but I'd like to make a custom underline with box-shadow effect. So I have two issues.

1. my border is showing up all the time, not just when I hover.
2. When I tried to add a box shadow to my .underline class it goes around the whole list item and does not create a separate line.  I guess we can get to this item later.

MY CSS CODE

```
li {
    margin: auto 0px 20px auto;
    font: 1em 'Bookman Old Style', Georgia, Garamond, ‘Times New Roman’, Times, serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    display: block;
}

li a:hover .underline {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.underline {
    border-bottom: #FFFFFF solid 2px;
}
```

MY HTML CODE

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="underline" href="http://www.sitepoint.com/">SitePoint.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-sliding-menu/">Revealing CSS3 Menu</a></li>
</ul>
```

I would really like to be pointed to a comprehensive article about how to build rich HTML elements via CSS specfically using :before and :after and being able to use multiple classes on one selector in CSS properly.

Here is a JSFiddle of what I have (broken) http://jsfiddle.net/jellis3d/a8svpwr4/2/.  Also here is a picture of what I'm after.  I really exaggerated the underline in order to show what I'm looking for.  The line does not have to have rounded edges either.
[image]

Comment: It works fine for me JSFiddle demo [edited] - http://jsfiddle.net/9f7bvbue/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by apply `border-bottom` to `.underline:hover` and `box-shadow` and `display: inline-block;` to `li a` tag.

### JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9f7bvbue/8/)

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="underline" href="http://www.sitepoint.com/">SitePoint.com</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-sliding-menu/">Revealing CSS3 Menu</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background: gray; /* only for demo */
}
li {
    margin: auto 0px 20px auto;
    font: 1em'Bookman Old Style', Georgia, Garamond, ‘Times New Roman’, Times, serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #000;
}
li a:hover .underline {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
.underline:hover {
    border-bottom: #FFFFFF solid 2px;
}
```

Comment: @Jhaller "my border is showing up all the time, not just when I hover." - do you want the border on hover? like this - http://jsfiddle.net/a8svpwr4/4/

Comment: Okay.  I just updated my Fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/jellis3d/a8svpwr4/6/.  I noticed that the Fiddle is not making the text 100% white on hover.  However, on my local machine with Aptana and Firefox(latest version) it is working.

Comment: The other thing I would like is for the line to transition in from the left side of the screen and fade or transition out smoothly when the mouse rolls off of it.

Comment: @Jhaller Now it's white text - http://jsfiddle.net/a8svpwr4/7/ and I'm working on second point...

Comment: @Jhaller "the line to transition in from the left side" - do you mean the `border-bottom: #FFFFFF solid 5px;`???

Comment: Opps, didn't see I had some } junk in there.  Thanks for catching that on my Fiddle.

Comment: Right.  Right now I'm using the border-bottom as a place holder until I can figure out how to get the customized line add, like I have in my picture above.  How do I create a customized line like that without it being put around the whole link?

Comment: @Jhaller you could use [border-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image) and it will also work on hover.

Comment: @Jhaller check it out - http://jsfiddle.net/a8svpwr4/12/ **and** http://jsfiddle.net/a8svpwr4/13/

Comment: sorry for extended discussion.  I would like to use CSS so I would even settle for a border-bottom with a drop shadow if I had to.  Is there anyway to get the line to ease out more smoothly?  What about the transition from the left if just a border bottom?

Comment: @Jhaller `500ms ease-in-out` - http://jsfiddle.net/a8svpwr4/15/ :( "transition from the left" - its a border... and have you checked my this comment??? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815333/selctorhover-class-applied-before-hover/25815678#comment40385348_25815678

Comment: Made an update to Fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/jellis3d/a8svpwr4/17/.  This is looking like we're on the right track.  Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

i have made a basic demo on js fiddle showing what i think your after

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/bkLwk5u7/)

it uses the below css which im sure you can then see what i did and make it into what your after.

```
li a{
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:none;
}
li a:hover{
    color:red;
    border-bottom: black solid 1px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;    
}
```

Comment: I uploaded a demo and a picture.

Comment: @Jhaller being friday well.. but i got home saw your reply showing what your after this isnt exact but it is displayed the same but each element like a harpsichord 1 above the other [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/bkLwk5u7/) let me know what you think and il get back to you asap

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a box-shadow effect on hovering, right? You don't need to use an extra element like `.underline` then. Just add it to `li a:hover`

```
li a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

You can read more about pseudo-elements like :before and :after on W3C: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp

I made a small demo with your code using :before on hover: http://jsfiddle.net/m9czpzs5/